# How to make a search box visible on a web page in zoom mode when set to focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

When i am in 100% zoom mode and when i set focus to a search box on a web page i am able to see the whole search box with out any issues, but if i am in 200% zoom mode and if i set the focus to the search box then i am seeing only half of the search box. In any zoom mode how to make sure that the whole search box is visible to the user.

Code:

```
<input id="searchbox" title="SearchBox" height= 100% padding = 0 5px 0 15px width=200px border-style="none">
```

Above is search box input element code.My search box inside of a webpage where i cant change width and padding as it is overlapping with other elements. Is there any way when it is focused the page is scrolled such that it is shown completely

Comment: Do you have a sample URL with this in action? My first reaction is to not worry, as users who zoom into a control mostly need to see the control, not necessarily the entire control nor content around it.

Comment: you cant access the url

Comment: My search box is having a drop down button which will enable users to see options, in zoom mode only half of search box is visible so user is unable to see drop down button

Comment: In a vacuum, because I cannot see it, perhaps a `max-width` and expect that users who zoom will be aware that things get truncated / clipped.

Comment: @aardrian in zoom mode of stack over flow only the search box on top is truncated, when tabbing or on clicking the search box, only some part of search box is visible. how to make it visible completely in this situation?

Comment: If the clipping does not prevent some functionality, then do not worry about it. Making the box completely visible will still clip the same amount of text at the window/screen edge, so it does not necessarily improve the experience. Do not scale the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.elementClass').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

In any zoom mode your element will be focused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the box-sizing and width of the search input field. Here is the code will work for you even at 400% zoom.

```
.searchbox{  
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:7px 10px;
width:100%;
}

<input id="searchbox" title="SearchBox" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search...">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can just try CSS hover effects, ie while hovering you can increase the size of the input field

```
#searchbox:hover{  
  /* Increase size or padding */
}
```